# How to use fork() to iterate/search through a 3D/multi dimension int array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d, fork

Hi guys I'm trying to get some practice out using fork() and with multi dimention arrays.

so i'm trying to tell my program to go through a 3D array where I assigned it at specific locations a certain number and to search through the whole array for that specific number and give me back where it found it.

now I want to use fork() just for practice sake for this. the compiler is giving me a bunch of errors related to both the array itself and the fork()
this what i got so far:

```
int i,j,k;
int this[100][100][100];
int charlie;    //charlie is what i called the result of the a iteration
this[30][2][4]=23;
this[20][1][3]=23;
this[80][19][90]=23;

void ChildProcess()
{
printf("child\n");
    for (i=50;i<75;i++)
    {
            for(j=50;j<75;j++)
            {
                    for(k=50;k<75;k++)
                    {
                    charlie=this[i][j][k];
                    if(charlie==23)
                    {
                    printf("i=%d,j=%d,k=%d",i,j,k);
                    }
                    }
            }
    }
 } 

  void ParentProcess() 
  {
   printf("parent\n");

    for (i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<50;j++)
            {
                    for(k=0;k<50;k++)
                    {
                    charlie=this[i][j][k];
                    if(charlie==23)
                    {
                    printf("i=%d,j=%d,k=%d",i,j,k);
                    }
                    }
            }
       }  
    }

    void ChildProcess()
    {
    printf("child2\n");
    for (i=75;i<100;i++)
    {
            for(j=75;j<100;j++)
            {
                    for(k=75;k<100;k++)
                    {
                    charlie=this[i][j][k];
                    if(charlie==23)
                    {
                    printf("i=%d,j=%d,k=%d",i,j,k);
                    }
                    }
            }
        } 
    }

 int main()
 {

    int pid=fork();
    printf ("this is the pid %d\n",pid);

    if(pid!=0)
    {
    ParentProcess();
    }
    else
    {
    ChildProcess();
    }
    int pid2=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    {
    ChildProcess2();
    }
  }
```

one of the errors it gave me was: 
s.c:7:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default] this[30][2][4]=23;

and

s.c:5:5: note: previous declaration of ‘this’ was here int this[100][100][100];

these 2 errors keep popping up non stop. 
to be honest I'm not sure what it means since i didnt reclare it or smt

Comment: Cannot fix invisible errors, but try moving assignment statements to some function.

Comment: sorry for not making it clearer! one of the errors it gave me was:
s.c:7:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
 this[30][2][4]=23;
and
s.c:5:5: note: previous declaration of ‘this’ was here
 int this[100][100][100];

these 2 errors keep popping up non stop. to be honest I'm not sure what it  means since i didnt reclare it or smt

Comment: Please add any relevant information to the question itself using the edit button.

Comment: Why use fork instead of threads?

Comment: The first error message you report is telling you that lines like `this[30][2][4]=23;` cannot appear outside the body of a function.  You could use C99 designated initializers: `int this[100][100][100] = { [30] = { [2] = { [4] = 23 } }, [20] = { [1] = { [3] = 23 } }, [80] = { [19] = { [90] = 23 } } };` to set the array.

Comment: Im trying to use fork() just for sake of practicing!